# Larger color variance for frequent values GNUplot

Tags: gnuplot, gradient

I've got data in the following format:

```
x   y   value
1   1   3
1   2   3
1   3   3
2   1   4
2   2   4
2   3   4
3   1   5
3   2   6
3   3   7
```

In this example, values 3 and 4 occur most frequently in the 3*3 grid. The goal is to create an image of a surface, and the color of the coordinate is depends on the 'value'. Please keep in mind that this is just an example, in practice I have a grid of about 500*150 coordinates with values ranging up to roughly 1000. I currently plot an image like this:

```
plot "data.csv" u 1:2:3 with points pt 5 ps variable palette
```

The thing is, given the example, the colors of 3 and 4 would be similar using a standard pallete. This gets worse when the amount of different values increases.

What I would like, is that the colors of values with the highest frequency are most substantially different from each other. I want this because due to the nature of the data, there are often values that are close in value and high frequency at the same time compared to the rest of the data. So given the example, I would for instance desire 3 to be blue and 4 to be red. If there would be more values that don't occur much like the values 5, 6 and 7, I'd still like the colors of 3 and 4 to be very much apart; again like blue and red. The whole point is that it would be easy to distinguish high frequency values due to their color.

I think the above will be difficult to do, this could be an alternative: as an alternative I would like a 'fast' gradient for low values, for example from values 1 to 10 a rainbow gradient, excluding for instance blue. Then, for the values 11-1000 for instance, I'd like a 'slow' gradient towards the remaining color (blue in this example, or perhaps some range of remaining colors). This would also somewhat suffice as it would imply low values to have more differentiating colors, and due to the nature of the data lower values tend to occur more often. I imagine this to be an easier solution, so if you have a solution for this but not for the first one, please mention it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible palette as starting point:

```
set terminal postscript eps color
set output 'test.eps'
set palette defined (0 1 0 1, 1 1 0 0, 2 1 1 0, 3 0 1 0, 100 0 0 1) maxcolor 2**12
test palette
set output
```

This gives the result:
[image]

I used the `postscript` terminal, because most of the other terminals support only 256 colors when using coloring by palette. Of course, you could use `lc rgb variable` instead. Then the last column is interpreted as integer representation of an rgb value, but you would have to specify the complete color function including interpolation etc. by yourself.

Comment: Forgot the most obvious way: use a logscale for your color data.

Comment: Excellent, thanks a lot. This actually makes a lot of sense. Unfortunately it requires some manual tweaking compared to coloring based on frequency, but this will do (it already allowed me to generate some nice images). If you have any suggestions on how to use a logscale for this, please share. I think however this will be more useful to me as it allows for some manual tweaking.

Comment: With logscale I meant, that you can just do something like `plot "data.csv" u 1:2:(log($3))` with a linear color palette.